# Why does Visual Studio Code shows path before the actual output When using Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[image: image for output]

why does vsc show this when running the program

Comment: That's the command that VSC executes to run your java program

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Alexander Makarov said, these are execution scripts and VS Code displays them to let developers know what's going on during this process.

[image]

From your screenshot, we can know:

1. You're debugging a project and this is your debug script execution path;
2. This process uses jdk-14 as java version to compile, and coding style is UTF-8;
3. The current project cache is stored in this directory;
4. hello is the name of current debugging .java file.

This is a default setting provided by VS Code, and if you don't like it, @anurag saxena had provided a way, also installing the extension **Code Runner** is another choice. Add the following code in settings.json:

```
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

Then every time you run code, there's no execution script before the ouput.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behavior in VS code, so to hide unnecessary info
you can go in

preferences-> settings and search for (Java › Debug › Settings: Console) Change its setting from default to (internalconsole) and that's it. you will get a terminal path free output on debug console